# Google script Array values is getting only Null

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function getID(){
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SheetID");   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DVAL1");   //var rec =
     sheet.getRange("B"+1).getValue();

       var currentRowAT = 1;
         var currentCellValueAT = "start";
         while (currentCellValueAT != ""){
           if (currentCellValueAT = sheet.getRange("B" + currentRowAT).getValue() != ""){
           var actualvalue = sheet.getRange("B" + currentRowAT).getValue();
             var rowValues = [];
             Logger.log(actualvalue);
             rowValues[currentRowAT]=actualvalue;
           currentRowAT = currentRowAT +1;
           }
         }
         Logger.log(rowValues); 
      }
```

RESULT :

```
[15-12-28 00:06:15:693 PST] 1.0 [15-12-28 00:06:15:799 PST] 2.0
 [15-12-28 00:06:15:896 PST] 3.0 [15-12-28 00:06:16:014 PST] 4.0
 [15-12-28 00:06:16:118 PST] 5.0 [15-12-28 00:06:16:239 PST] 6.0
 [15-12-28 00:06:16:340 PST] 7.0 [15-12-28 00:06:16:442 PST] 8.0
 [15-12-28 00:06:16:534 PST] 9.0 [15-12-28 00:06:16:631 PST] 10.0
 [15-12-28 00:06:16:727 PST] 11.0 [15-12-28 00:06:16:824 PST] 12.0
 [15-12-28 00:06:16:919 PST] 13.0 [15-12-28 00:06:17:014 PST] 14.0
 [15-12-28 00:06:17:107 PST] 15.0 [15-12-28 00:06:17:154 PST] [null,
 null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
 null, null, null, 15.0]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: removed quote and added code tag

Answer (score 0):

You are using syntax for adding an element to a JSON object rather than an array method.  This line:

```
rowValues[currentRowAT]=actualvalue;
```

Change to:

```
rowValues.push(actualvalue);
```

And move this line:

```
var rowValues = [];
```

**out** of the `while` loop.   It's resetting the array to an empty array on every loop.